# List modification doesn't change list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to reverse a string, so I converted the string into a list and was trying to send the last element to the front, 2nd to last element to the 2nd space, etc.

```py
word = input("Enter a word: ")

word = list(word)
count = 0

while count < len(word):
    word.insert(count, word.pop())
    count = count + 1

print(word)
```

It just returns the original string in list form, even though I'm saving the last letter and inserting it before popping it off of the string? Does word.pop() not capture the last letter of a string before deleting it or am I overlooking something?

Comment: It doesn't return *anything*, there is no `return` statement.

Comment: You will benefit from reading this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: ^ Also [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: You can also use this website to see what the code is doing wrong: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simplest way to do what you are trying is to slice the string in reverse order, this does not even require changing into a list:

```py
word = input("Enter a word: ")
return word[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an experiment:

```
>>> word = list('python')
>>> word.insert(0, word[-1])
>>> word
['n', 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
>>> word.remove(word[-1])
>>> word
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

Wait, what?!

```
>>> help(word.remove)
Help on built-in function remove:

remove(value, /) method of builtins.list instance
    Remove first occurrence of value.

    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
```

> Remove *first* occurrence of value.

So, you inserted `word[-1]` at the beginning of the list, and then `word.remove` immediately removes the *first* occurrence of `word[-1]`, which is now at the beginning of the list, you've just inserted it there!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the variables inside the `while-loop` to the same value. Also, use `list.pop` to remove the element from the list. For example:

```py
word = input("Enter a word: ")

word = list(word)
count = 0

while count < len(word):
    word.insert(count, word.pop())
    count = count + 1

print(word)
```

Prints:

```
Enter a word: book
['k', 'o', 'o', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the docstring for `list.remove`:

```
>>> help(list.remove)
Help on method_descriptor:

remove(self, value, /)
    Remove first occurrence of value.
    
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

>>>
```

As you can see, `list.remove` removes the first occurrence of the given value from the list. All your `backwards` function does right now is take the last character of the word, add it to the front and then immediately remove it from the front again. You do this once for every character in the word, the net result being no change.